# Oracle Query is not being executed

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, web-services

I'm trying to retrieve values from an Oracle database using C# WebMethod, ajax and JavaScript, I have another page with exactly all the same functions and methods (using MSSQL Database) and work fine, but now I want to do it with Oracle. This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Oracle.DataAccess.Client;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for OracleConexion
/// </summary>
public class OracleConexion
{
    OracleConnection conn;
    DataTable dt;
    OracleDataAdapter da;
    OracleDataReader dr;
    DataSet ds;
    OracleCommand cmd;

    public OracleConexion()
    {
        conn = new OracleConnection("Data Source = (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = ***.**.**.***)(PORT = ****)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SID = *****))); User Id = *****; Password = ****;");
    }

    private void Open()
    {
        string canConnect;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            canConnect = "Nice";
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Code Updated
            canConnect = ex.Message.ToString();    
        }
        Console.Write(canConnect);
    }

    private void Close()
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public DataTable ConsultarTablas(string opcion)
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        ds = new DataSet();
        string sql = "";
        switch (opcion)
        {
            case "Datos":
                sql = "Select Component as Result from BOM_Explosion where TOP_MATERIAL = '-FHN7092A-EF' and ROWNUM <= 5;";
                break;

        }
        try
        {
            Open();
            OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            da.Fill(ds);
            dt = ds.Tables[0];
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            Close();
        }
        return dt;
    }
}
```

And this is my WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]

public string ObtenerDatosNumeroParte()   
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt = conn.ConsultarTablas("Datos");
    Ticket ti;
    List<Ticket> lista = new List<Ticket>();
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)   
    {
        ti = new Ticket();            
        ti.Vs = dt.Rows[i]["Result"].ToString();

        lista.Add(ti);
        ti = null;
    }

    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    string lineas = js.Serialize(lista);
    return lineas;
}
```

Testing it seems like my code do not execute my query and my List always is null, what I'm doing wrong and what can I do to solve it?

**Update**

Using my string `canConnect` I get `ORA-6413: Connection not open.`

Comment: Why not fill directly the data Table ?

Comment: You have empty catch exceptions. Why? What's the point in catching if you don't do anything about it? Silently failing means it's going to be difficult to figure out when things go wrong.